# Nginx location match if not equal

Tags: nginx, rewrite, rewritecond

I have www.example.com/test and i want to write a condition if requested url is not equal to /test do a rewrite or redirect to www.example.com. The closest i can get is a code below but when i want to use www.example.com/test without / at the end it redirects me to www.example.com but when i type www.example.com/test/ it works.

```
location / 
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;

if ($request_uri !~ ^/test/(.*)$)
{return 301 $scheme://www.example.com;}

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nginx If**

Generally with Nginx you [avoid using the IF statement](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). It takes more resources and doesn't always work how you want.

**Solution**

The way you do this is to define two locations, catchall and test.

```
# I just copied this from above, you might want it in a block
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;

# Return permanent redirect for everything other than the /test URL
# Suggest you use 302 until you have this working perfectly. Google / browsers
# caches 301 redirects for a long time
location / {
  return 301 $scheme://www.example.com;
}

location /test {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

I think this will work for both /test and /test/ . If not you could try this, which might work

```
location ~* /test
```

You should read up on how Nginx works, particularly location block matching. I think [this article is likely to be useful](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms).